# How do I find a leak in PEX plumbing?

Tags: plumbing, leak, testing

I've finished my PEX supply-side plumbing rough in.

I put a Schrader valve into a push-connect fitting and attached it to one open end and threaded a pressure gauge into another push-connect fitting and attached it to another open end. Then I connected a hot/cold pair of lines to make a closed system, then plugged the rest of the openings with test plugs and put test plugs into all the shower/tub outlets.

I pressurized the system to about 80PSI. Within a few minutes it had dropped to 74PSI, then by the time I was done with dinner it was down to about 50PSI.

I've listened & felt every single joint in the new plumbing - I cannot hear or feel any air escaping. I've sprayed soapy water on all the joints and I don't see any bubbles forming. I've even tested the connections at the valve & pressure gauge to make sure they weren't the source of the leak.

What other methods are there for finding where the plumbing is leaking?

Comment: There's only air in the system, @JD74, no water yet. Sure, the air coming out of the compressor is reasonably hot, but I wouldn't expect it to loose 30PSI in an hour or so due to cooling. I use the same compressor & hose to fill my tires and don't have that issue. (Unless I pick up a screw or nail in the driveway...)

Comment: Do you have shutoffs where you can narrow down where the leak might be occurring? What about filling the system with water and looking for leaks? I've also seen smoke used in automotive diagnosis for AC line leaks, but that required a special machine.

Comment: PEX expands. It could be if you have a lot of lines they are expanding and the pressure drops.  There should be a limit to the expansion. See if it stabilizes and then try adding a bit more air.  If the pressure doesn't drop the lines were expanding rather than leaking.

Comment: There was a glimmer of hope, but it's down to 26 PSI now, @RMDman

Comment: I've only got valves to the shower/tub @UnhandledExcepSean. There _will be_ valves below every faucet, but they're not installed yet. Good idea, though, I'll shut those off and repressurize to see if it makes a difference. If it does, I can play "turn the valve" after that.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like a leak.   I have only used the water pressure to test any of mine.

Comment: I did actually think about just turning the water on (this is an addition, so water's live elsewhere in the house. I'd presume I'd find a fresh wet spot, but I don't really want to have to deal with cleaning up water as I pop off the crimp rings. I may not have a choice. :(

Comment: @Freeman,  my wife and the neighbors know to give me any old beach or shower towels.  I stuff one or 2 of those around wherever I have to make a repair.  They suck up a lot of water.

Comment: Hey, uh... @UnhandledExcepSean... If you want to expand "shut offs" to include "drain valves", I'd swallow my pride and upvote that as an answer... The drain valve was open _just_ enough to let air out. But it was leaking so slowly that I could neither feel nor hear it - I did check this valve, I swear! With that closed completely, the system's been holding 80 PSI for about 20 hours now.

Comment: @FreeMan Glad to hear you found the leak :)

Comment: TBH, that drain valve is in the unfinished root cellar, so if I'd just turned on the water, I'd have found it pretty quickly! That's where _all_ our plumbing has been until this addition. I didn't really want to button up walls only to discover that there was a small leak somewhere, or, alternatively a _very large_ leak like the first one I found where I'd put a pipe on a fitting but forgot to put a crimp ring on it. Not even slipped in place, just... missing... Much better to discover that with air!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have shutoff valves, you can narrow the parts of the system where the leak might be occurring by shutting off runs of piping and monitoring the pressure.

Also, be sure your drain valves (if you have any) are not leaking and are closed completely.

Comment: Silly drain valve... :(

Answer (score 1):

Soapy water (or the not-so-secret trick of adding some glycerin, or buying bubble-wand solution from the toy aisle) has always worked for me, including on a quite slow leak in my floor-heat PEX loop.

The glycerin (which is commonly in the bubble wand solution) helps with bubble persistence. I think you can also buy bubble-wand solution at 10 times the price as leak detection fluid ;^)

Under the heading of "I don't think you'd ever do this in home plumbing" more exotic leak detection using a helium gas fill and a helium detector is a thing, but it's "an expensive mostly used in laboratories" thing, as far as I know.

Comment: You sure the bubble-wand solution is _more_ expensive than leak detection fluid? I'd think it would be the other way around. Either way, I'll probably pick something up tomorrow on my way home and give that a shot.  Thanks!

Comment: If I went the helium route, I'd have the joy of talking funny while I fixed the leak! :)